# python how to inherit parent stack

Tags: python, class

hey guys i am new to data structure and i havee been wondering how to inherit a parent class attributes.
I am trying to inherit the attributes of stack(parent) to stack3(child) but the error keeps popping up: TypeError: **init**() missing 1 required positional argument: '_Stack3__list'
Any help or suggestions would be appreciated!

```
class Stack:
  def __init__(self):
    self.__list= []
  def isEmpty(self):
    return self.__list == []
  def size(self):
    return len(self.__list)
  def clear(self):
    self.__list.clear() 
  def push(self, item):
    self.__list.append(item)
  def pop(self):
    if self.isEmpty():
      return None
    else:
      return self.__list.pop()
  def get(self):
    if self.isEmpty():
      return None
    else:
      return self.__list[-1]
  def __str__(self):
    output = '<'
    for i in range( len(self.__list) ):
      item = self.__list[i]
      if i < len(self.__list)-1 :
        output += f'{str(item)}, '
      else:
        output += f'{str(item)}'
    output += '>'
    return output

class Stack3(Stack):
  def __init__(self,__list):
    self.__list = __list
    super().__init__(self.__list)
  def printMe(self):
    super().__str__()

s = Stack3()
print(s.pop())
for i in range(1,6):
  s.push(i)
print('Content of stack =',s)
print('Item at top=',s.get())
print('Size=', s.size())
while not s.isEmpty():
  print(s.pop())
  print(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass all arguments from `Stack3.__init__` to `Stack. __init__` use:

```
class Stack3(Stack):
  def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

see [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-args-and-kwargs-in-python-3) for a detailed explanation of `*args` and `**kwargs` usage.